# How can i add or set more email tokens in my drupal 6 site

Tags: 6

I would like to add more `email token` variables in my `Drupal 6` site.I have found some of the variables like `!username, !temp, !site, !password, !uri, !uri_brief`.Is there any way by which i could add more `tokens` and `assign` these `token variables` in my `custom module`.Could I accomplish this by using some `contributed module` or `programatically`.Hope someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want more tokens in the users settings page `admin/user/settings` (D6), according the format of your token (!username)

This page is a bit special because it is a core feature.
cf [User settings](https://drupal.org/getting-started/6/admin/user/settings)

[Token module](https://drupal.org/project/token) provides more tokens like [my-token] but this cannot be applied in the `admin/user/settings`

If you want more tokens on the users settings, i suggest to use a custom rule (fire on user's creation) with the [rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules)